# iOS - Getting Status bar height & width 0 in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

When I am trying to open the app in landscape mode in iPhoneX, I am getting the following two values 0. It should be 44 right ? Because of that unable to click the hamburger

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height`
`UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by using

```
window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
```

For Ex:

```
let safeFrame = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame;
let safeFrameHeight = safeFrame.origin.y;
let safeFrameWidth = safeFrame.origin.x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Status Bar not showed (Hidden) in landscape mode @Mallikarjuna

You can check by print out below codes :

`po view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height`

you can use safeAreaInset for get 44px value

`UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.left // safeAreaInsets.left -> for your case`

[image]

Comment: yes, but when I am moving the view 44px right side then I am to click. Here 44px is statusbar width. Right ?

Comment: how can we get that 44 in landscape mode. I am getting 0

Comment: you're Wellcome

Comment: Thanks for the `safeAreaInsets` tip, it solved my issue.